# Awk conditional with multiple conditions

Tags: awk

I am using awk to check if my data has values of 32th column is greater than 4000 and value of 60th column is less than 10. I am using below command, but it is not working, nor it is showing any error:

```
awk -F, '$32 > 4000' && '$60 < 10' *
```

I have `,` as separator and I am checking it in all the files in a folder.

Comment: Do you mean row or column? Because you appear to try to check columns.

Comment: My Mistake. Its column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

awk evaluates conditions within `' '` and you have two blocks of them, `&&` being outside. So you have to put all this syntax within `' '`:

```
awk -F, '$32 > 4000 && $60 < 10' *
```

Instead of:

```
awk -F, '$32 > 4000' && '$60 < 10' *
                   ^    ^
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just combine multiple condition within one quote and use it like:

```
awk -F, '$32 > 4000 && $60 < 10' *
```